# Parsing a json array in android

Tags: android, json

I am writing an android code to parse a json array. I am not sure how it is to be done. I have however tried to parse the array.

These are the following things that I need to do:

I want to store the "status" in a variable.

Also, I want to store "ButtonImageUrl", "ImageUrl",  "Title", "Url" iteratively in a string.

If anyone could guide me how should I proceed it would be very helpful.

```
{
  "first": {
    "message": "",
    "status": "Success"
  },
  "second": [
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    },
    {
      "ButtonImageUrl": "string1",
      "ImageUrl": "string2",
      "Title": "string3",
      "Url": "string4"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Code:

```
private void jsonrequest2()
{

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try
            {

                jsonArray = null;
                jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("second");
                //jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("second");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i = 0 ; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {

                try
                {

                    ExampleItem exampleItem = new ExampleItem();

                    exampleItem.setmText1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));
                    exampleItem.setmText2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title"));
                    exampleItem.setImageUrl(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ButtonImageUrl"));
                    //jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Title")

                    exampleList.add(exampleItem);

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }



            setuprecyclerview(exampleList);



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ProductPage1.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);


}
```

Comment: Use gson library to parson json to POJO https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: your `response` is not a `JSONArray`, it is a `JSONObject`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sir, can you please check if the updated code is correct or not.

Comment: Same incorrect. Your JSON is the JSON object, while you are doing a  `JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sir I have changed the JSONArray reponse to JSONObject reponse and changed the code accordingly. Sir can you please have a look at the code.

Comment: ok, now looks good. So what is the problem now?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko The entire code snippet shows syntax error.

Comment: which syntax error?

Comment: probably you need not  `JsonArrayRequest` since you are requesting a JSONObject, not JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the response is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray.
Your code should look something like this.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    //Storing status into a variable
    try{
        JSONObject firstObject = response.getJSONObject("first");
        String status = firstObject.getString("status");

        //Accessing the JSONArray
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("second");
        String mButtonImageUrl, mUrl, mImageUrl, mTitle;
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject innerObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mButtonImageUrl = innerObject.getString("ButtonImageUrl");
            mUrl = innerObject.getString("Url");
            mImageUrl = innerObject.getString("ImageUrl");
            mTitle = innerObject.getString("Title");

            //These variables will be updated in every iteration. Store them or use them as you want here. 
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//...
```